# Create several outgoing connections simultaneously in Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I'm using Java NIO for a peer to peer protocol and need to create many simultaneous connections of which many will fail. Unfortunately, it seems as if I need to wait for a connection to be established before creating the next one, otherwise I'll get a "BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect". Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
for (NetworkAddress address : addresses) {
    if (isConnectedTo(address)) {
        continue;
    }
    try {
        SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address.toInetAddress(), address.getPort()));
        // admittedly, 20 seconds is quite long
        long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 20_000;
        while (!channel.finishConnect() && System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout) {
            // Without this loop, I get said exception
        }
        if (!channel.finishConnect()) {
            channel.close();
            continue;
        }
        ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo(ctx, CLIENT,
            address,
            listener,
            requestedObjects, 0
        );
        connections.put(
            connection,
            channel.register(selector, OP_READ | OP_WRITE, connection)
        );
    } catch (NoRouteToHostException | AsynchronousCloseException ignore) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never catch an exception and do not Handle it. Like your noroutetohostexception

Comment: You can't use the connection before it has finished connecting but you can have any number of pending connections.

Comment: @Jens: I almost agree, but I expect that there is no route to some hosts, and there is nothing to do except trying the next one. The other one is also expected (happens on shutting down) but I might want to log if it happens on other occasions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Can't I register it to my selector? Then how do I know I can start using it? Edit: I'm stupid, I need to register it with OP_CONNECT. If you make that a proper answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the connection before it has finished connecting but you can have any number of pending connections

You can either

- poll you connecting connection to see if they have connected yet, or
- add the connection to a Selector by registering an OP_CONNECT.

In either case I suggest calling `finishConnect()` to ensure it is ready for use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I've got it working now, although I'll need to do some more tests to make sure. There was a minor behaviour change in the other (and more widely used) Bitmessage client that I didn't notice until yesterday, resulting in considerably more failed connections in my client. I need to fix this in order to make sure the network code now works properly.